# What's missing in TFS Express?

Tags: tfs, version-control

I know there are some limitations to use the express edition of TFS: only compatible with SQL Express, no reporting service. Can anyone tell me more?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2012/02/23/coming-soon-tfs-express.aspx

Comment: I'm really curious about the size limitations.. I just went and created ~10 TFS projects, it appear as if they are all stored in the same database.

I just wonder how much of this information is stored in blobs, and if it's stored as blobs, we can move to to FileStream data and really basically extend the life of TFS Express.

I only have a single user, but I'm a bit of a power user ;)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I googled 'TFS Express Limitations'

> The Express edition is essentially the same TFS as you get when you
>   install the TFS Basic wizard except that the install is trimmed down
>   and streamlined to make it incredibly fast and easy. In addition to
>   the normal TFS Basic install limitations (no Sharepoint integration,
>   no reporting), TFS Express:
>
> - Is limited to no more than 5 named users.
> - Only supports SQL Server Express Edition (which we’ll install for you, if you don’t have it)
> - Can only be installed on a single server (no multi-server configurations)
> - Excludes the TFS Proxy and the new Preemptive analytics add-on.

Comment: I see the Backup tab is also missing...?

Comment: Backup is included in express version