# Limitations & Features of TFS Express 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, checkin, vcs-checkout

I want to know the features and limitations of TFS express 2013. Such as Check in and check out options, how many users can be configured and regarding sql server versions it supports and so on.

Comment: Then why not go and read the documentation on the Microsoft web site?

Comment: I am getting it for 2012 express but not for 2013 express

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever here is why I prefer to read SO rather than a vendor's website: 1) SO answers are typically concise, 2) SO allows others to comment so I can get different POV, and 3) Vendors generally hide information order to "trick" you into reading more of their website.  I have to keep digging on their website to satisfy myself that I have found all information.  I trust my fellow SOers to have installed the software and uncovered the things the vender is hiding.  Thank you @ thevan for asking this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this:

- [What's missing in TFS Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10926189/whats-missing-in-tfs-express)

  > The Express edition is essentially the same TFS as you get when you
  >   install the TFS Basic wizard except that the install is trimmed down
  >   and streamlined to make it incredibly fast and easy. In addition to
  >   the normal TFS Basic install limitations (no Sharepoint integration,
  >   no reporting), TFS Express:
  >
  > - Is limited to no more than 5 named users.
  > - Only supports SQL Server Express Edition (which we’ll install for you, if you don’t have it)
  > - Can only be installed on a single server (no multi-server configurations)
  > - Excludes the TFS Proxy and the new Preemptive analytics add-on.
  > - And also no backlog board or task board...
  > - I see the Backup tab is also missing...?
  > - Backup is included in express version
  > - Do we know whether CodeLens works with TFS Express?
  > - CodeLens works with TFS Express.
- https://lajak.wordpress.com/2013/01/09/tfs-2012-versions-of-team-foundation-server/

> **Team Foundation Server Express**
>   TFS Express is a free limited version of Team Foundation Server. It is
>   great for small teams of up to 5 five users. TFS Express can be
>   downloaded from the MSDN website and it is around 500MB. Here is a
>   direct link to the TFS Express home page.
>
> Pro’s
>
> - Free
> - Data stays inside your network
> - Comes with version control repository
> - Work item tracking
> - Build Automation
> - You have more control compared to the TFS Service
> - Can customize Process and Workitems template
> - CAL’s can be purchased in case your team grows beyond 5 users
> - Support for express versions of Visual Studio
>
> Con’s
>
> - Must have own hardware or virtual machine
> - Not accessible from anywhere
> - Supports Basic installation only
> - Limited Agile Project management features and tools
> - No Reporting Integration
> - No SharePoint Integration
> - Supports only SQL Server Express Edition
> - Installed on one machine. Can’t scale out
> - Doesn’t support TFS Proxy
> - Excludes Preemptive analytics add-on
> - Need to manage your own database backups and downtimes in case of hardware failure
> - Buy license for the Operating System and CALs if required

- social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8f99b8b8-4406-4fb4-b326-4cff50683b8c/tfs-2012-free-vs-commercial?forum=tfsversioncontrol

> In addition, there are some other limitations for TFS express.
>
> - Only supports SQL server Express edition.
> - Can only be installed on a single server.
>
> You can get more information form Brian Harry's blog TFS Express (blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2012/02/23/coming-soon-tfs-express.aspx)

Comment: [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."