# Integration of TFS Express to SQL Server Data Tools

Tags: tfs, version-control, sql-server-data-tools

We are using **Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2012** for our SSIS Packages development. We would like to integrate this with Team Foundation Server Express edition since it is free.

Please let me know whether this integration possible at all? What will be other limitations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server Data Tools is a feature in VS, while TFS is a server that provides features like source code management, reporting, ect. If Visual Studio 2012 is not installed, you need to install [Team Explorer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30656) to work with TFS.

Regarding TFS Express limitation, you may check this case: [Limitations & Features of TFS Express 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31556206/limitations-features-of-tfs-express-2013)

By the way, instead of TFS Express, you may consider using [Visual Studio Team Service](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-team-services-vs).